# Json returns null in swift

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am trying to get value from a json file but it returns null.

Here is the code:

```
     Alamofire.request( jsonUrl).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {


            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)["value"]
            print(swiftyJsonVar)
            let temp = swiftyJsonVar["value"]
            print(temp)
        }
    }
```

Here is the output from swiftyJsonVar:

```
[
  {
    "value" : "13.1",
    "quality" : "G",
    "date" : 1564772400000
  }
]
```

And the output from temp is null.

Why is temp null and not 13.1?

Comment: Use JSON(responseData.result.value!)[0]["value"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be an array: `responseData.result.value`

The array contains a dictionary with a key named `value`

So you should take first element of the array and then take the value of the `value` key like this:

```
JSON(responseData.result.value!)[0]["value"]
```

### - A better way to work with a JSON:

Take a look at **[Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable)**. This is much better way to deal with json.

with `Codable` you first define your object:

```
struct MyDTO {
    let value: String,
    let quality: String,
    let date: Int // or any type you need
}
```

Then you decode it with a `JSONDecoder`:

```
let results = try! JSONDecoder().decode([MyDTO].self, from: responseData)
```

and lastly you can access your needed item like this:

```
results.first!.value
```

Remember to handle `!` in a proper way.